# Blender 2.8 can no longer import module from Textblock

Tags: python

just downloaded todays Blender 2.8 build and it seems I can no longer import a function from another Textblock. Works well on a build from April 5th (haven't updated since then).

This simple example is not working in todays build:

[image: import module broken]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Solved: there was an API change. Thanks to @alyawn for posting the solution [here](https://devtalk.blender.org/t/2-80-using-multiple-internal-scripts-breaking-change/6980)

This is how it works now:
[image]

```
something = bpy.data.texts['something.py'].as_module()
```

Comment: I can't figure out how to do a "from mymodule import *", so I don't have to write the module name before every function.

Comment: @Tortenrandband  `globals().update(bpy.data.texts['something.py'].as_module().__dict__)`