# Blender 2.79 finds modules, but 2.80 does not

Tags: python, scripting, import

I'm new to blender, but not Python. I've been handed a blend script and asked to run it. There are a couple imports and I don't really understand where that code lives. In the Blender IDE and can look at these modules, but I don't know where the actual source code is. Is it in the blend file?

The reason I'm asking is because I can run the code in Blender 2.79 and blender finds the modules, but when I try to run the same code in Blender 2.80 it complains that it can't find the module.

I've seen post about appending to `sys.path` like this:

```
directory = os.path.dirname(bpy.data.filepath)
if not directory in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(directory)
```

and this script already does that so I don't think it's the problem.

**Why can Blender 2.79 find my modules, but Blender 2.80 can't? And where is the actual source code for the modules?**

Answer (score 2):

Apparently there was an API change and should have Googled harder. The answer is here [Blender 2.8 can no longer import module from Textblock](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/140005/blender-2-8-can-no-longer-import-module-from-textblock)